# how can I access to a variable in try block in other try block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, try-catch

http://blog.grossman.io/how-to-write-async-await-without-try-catch-blocks-in-javascript/ In this link, there are some codes that access to a variable in try catch but when I try this in my server It doesn't work because It's out of scope. how can I do this?

```
try {
  const foo = "bar"
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}

try {
  console.log(foo) -> is not defined
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The author of that post clearly did a mistake there––it happens to all of us.

So, the `const` declarations are block-scoped, like the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) say:

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. The value of a constant cannot change through re-assignment, and it can't be redeclared.

That's why you **cannot** access it outside of the try-catch block.

To solve the problem:

- Either use `var` instead of const:

  ```
  try {
    // When declared via `var`, the variable will
    // be declared outside of the block
    var foo = "bar"
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  try {
    console.log(foo)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
  ```
- Or you can declare the variable outside of the `try-catch`, using `let`:

  ```
  // Maybe it's clearer to declare it with let and 
  // assign the value in the first try-catch
  let foo;
  try {
    foo = "bar"
  } catch (e) {
     console.log(e)
  }

  try {
    console.log(foo)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
  ```

Comment: As you can see in the post, author use `const`, how does that work?

Comment: @PhillipYS I would say it's a mistake.

Comment: @PhillipYS I just tried it, yes, it's a mistake the author did. Nice catch!

Comment: Yeah I was wondering If scope system was changed after Node 8.0.0 is released. I hate try/catch so muchh

Comment: @PhillipYS No, it's not a change related to Node, but it's in the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).